# Unable to get content inside material-ui popover while testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, material-ui

In my component I've a `Popover` which has two `FloatingActionButtons` inside it. But I'm not able to check the existence of them in my test case. Here is what I have tried:

```
const fbuttons = TestUtils.scryRenderedComponentsWithType(popover, FloatingActionButton);
console.log(fbuttons) //[]
```

Here `popover` is the rendered `Popover` component. Any help would be much appreciated.